# How to run multiple test classes with a single command?

Tags: testing, flutter, automated-tests, integration-testing

I've started digging about how to run integration tests with Flutter and the pro/cons it has. 
Besides that the test output sometimes isn't helpful at all, I'd like to know if there's a way to run multiple dart classes with a single command.

Let's put an example where I've in my test_driver folder 4 classes:

- login.dart
- login_test.dart
- register.dart
- register_test.dart

In order to execute the tests on one of them, I'd do:

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/login.dart
```

Is there any way where I can avoid doing

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/login.dart
flutter drive --target=test_driver/register.dart
```

A posible workaround I've in mind is create a bash script to get all the files that doesn't end with "_test.dart" and execute that command.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run multiple integration tests with one single config file in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236606/can-i-run-multiple-integration-tests-with-one-single-config-file-in-flutter)