# Can I run multiple integration tests with one single config file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am trying to write Flutter integration tests and to run them all with one config file instead of making config file for every single test. Is there any way to do that?

For now I have `login.dart` and `login_test.dart` and so on, for every single test. I know its convention that every config and test file must have the same name, but that's not what I need, more configurable things are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

This is my config file: `login.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:seve/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();
  app.main();
}
```

And test: `login_test.dart` looks something like this

```dart
import ...

FlutterDriver driver;

void main() {
  setUpAll(() async {
    driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();
  });

  tearDownAll(() async {
    if (driver != null) {
      driver.close();
    }
  });

  test('T001loginAsDriverAndVerifyThatDriverIsLogedInTest', () async {
    some_code...
  });
}
```

Now I want to make new test file e.g `login_warning.dart` and be able to start both tests by calling single config file `login.dart`. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, running multiple "test" files with the same "config" is possible.

In the flutter jargon, your config file is your *target* and your test file is your *driver*. Your target is always `login.dart` but you have the two drivers `login_test.dart` and `login_warning.dart`.

With the `flutter drive` command, you can specify the `target` as well as the `driver`.

So in order to run both drivers, simply execute the following commands

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/login.dart --driver=test_driver/login_test.dart
flutter drive --target=test_driver/login.dart --driver=test_driver/login_warning.dart
```

This executes first the `login_test.dart` and then the `login_warning.dart` driver.

Comment: Thats sad... and ugly. But yes, it's the only solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can always have one main test file that you initiate, like say

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app_test.dart
```

Then in that call your test groups as functions, like so -

```
void main() {
  test1();
}
void test1() {
  group('test 1', () {});}
```

So with one command you get to execute all the cases mentioned in the `main()`

Answer (score 6):

Like vzurd's answer my favourit and cleanest is to create a single test file and call all main methods from within:

```
import './first_test.dart' as first;
import './second_test.dart' as second;

void main() {
  first.main();
  second.main();
}
```

Then just run driver on the single test file:

```
flutter drive --driver=test/integration/integration_test_driver.dart --target=test/integration/run_all_test.dart
```

Comment: This doesn't reset the state between two tests

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

to expand on to @sceee 's answer:

you can put the multiple commands into a shell script named `integration_tests.sh` for example and run them with a single command that way.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart --driver=test_driver/app_test.dart
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart --driver=test_driver/start_screen_test.dar
```

make executable:
`$chmod a+rx integration_tests.sh`
run it:
`$./integration_tests.sh`

Answer (score 0):

We can use shell command to automate this process.

The following solution will work even with any new test files without manually adding its name to any of the files.

1. Create a shell script with name `integrationTestRunner.sh` inside the root directory. You can use the command

   `touch integrationTestRunner.sh`
2. Inside `integrationTestRunner.sh` file, paste the following code.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Declare an array to store the file names and paths
declare -a targets

# Find all .dart files in the current directory and subdirectories
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
  targets+=("$file")
done < <(find integration_test -name "*.dart" -type f -print0)

# Loop through the array and run the flutter drive command for each target
for target in "${targets[@]}"
do
    flutter drive \
      --driver=test_driver/integation_test_driver.dart \
      --target=$target
done
```

3. Run the `integrationTestRunner.sh` file with any methods:

- Pressing the ▶️ button in that file (if you are in VS Code)
- Running the script from command line `./integrationTestRunner.sh`