# How to run multiple testing files with one config file in flutter without making long terminal command?

Tags: flutter, automated-tests, integration, flutter-test

I want to run multiple integration tests with one config file. By doing something like adding those files to a single file.

I found this answer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236606/can-i-run-multiple-integration-tests-with-one-single-config-file-in-flutter".Here the terminal command length is getting bigger as the test files are increasing.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvm4K.png) is the folder structure of testing in my project

I want to run both tests by running app.dart without using lengthy commands as below.

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/test_first/app.dart --driver=test_driver/test_first/app_test.dart flutter drive --target=test_driver/test_first/app.dart --driver=test_driver/test_first/login_test.dart
```

by doing something as below

```
import 'package:flutter_driver/driver_extension.dart';
import 'package:digiemo_flutter/main.dart' as app;

void main() {
  enableFlutterDriverExtension();

  //need to do something as below
  run app_test //some code to run first test
  run login_test //some code to run second test

  app.main();
 }
```

so the command should be:

```
flutter driver --target=test_driver/test_first/app.dart
```

something like that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run multiple integration tests with one single config file in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236606/can-i-run-multiple-integration-tests-with-one-single-config-file-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Simply give it the path of the folder

flutter drive --target=test_driver/test_first/